# Raspberry Pi becomes unresponsive when running opencv

Tags: video, opencv, streaming-video, webcam

I have successfully installed OpenCV on my Raspberry Pi and have been fooling around with some simple webcam streaming, live canny-edge detection, and so forth, all using basic C and C++ code. However, I'm running into problems with the two webcams I'm using. The first, a really basic, cheap Logitech I had sitting around, works fine, but the image quality leaves a LOT to be desired. But when I switch to my Logitech 510c camera, the image is much better, but the Pi freezes. Rather, the streaming program continues to run fine, but I can't exit the program - the Pi stops responding to the keyboard and the mouse, and the only way to quit is to unplug the Pi. Here's an example of some of the code:

```
#include <cv.h> 
#include <highgui.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){

  int c, i, j;

  //capture frame from camera
  CvCapture* capture = cvCaptureFromCAM(CV_CAP_ANY);
  if(!capture){
    fprintf(stderr, "Error: capture is NULL \n");
    getchar();
    return -1;
  }
  //set resolution of capture
  cvSetCaptureProperty(capture, CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 256);
  cvSetCaptureProperty(capture, CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, 192);

  //create window for display
  cvNamedWindow("canny");

  while(true){

    //find/mark edges using canny
    IplImage* frame = cvQueryFrame(capture);
    IplImage* grey = cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(frame), 8, 1);
    cvCvtColor(frame, grey, CV_RGB2GRAY);
    IplImage* frame2 = cvCreateImage(cvSize(grey->width+6, grey->height+6), grey->depth, grey->nChannels);

    CvPoint offset = cvPoint(3,3);
    cvCopyMakeBorder(grey, frame2, offset, IPL_BORDER_REPLICATE, cvScalarAll(0));
    IplImage* edges = cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(frame2), IPL_DEPTH_8U, frame2->nChannels);
    cvCanny(frame2, edges, 4900, 39200, 7);

    cvShowImage("canny", edges);

    //wait for a keypress
    int c = cvWaitKey(10);
    if (c!=-1) break;


  } //end while

  cvReleaseCapture (&capture);
  cvDestroyWindow("canny");
  return 0;

} //end main
```

Is there a problem with my code? Do I need to use a different webcam? I've overclocked the Pi; can it simply not handle the stream with a better-quality camera?

Comment: Is 256x192 a natural resolution for the camera or does opencv have to scale or crop it from something else.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried:

`lsmod`

`rmmod uvcvideo`

`modprobe uvcvideo nodrop=1 timeout=5000 quirks=0x80`

Also try to remove all "auto" settings through guvcview

It worked perfectly for me. It has been running för 24 hours straight with a steady 15fps @ 320x240.

Please check [this](http://www.raspberrypi.org/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?t=35689&p=300710) for details.

Cheers

Comment: I haven't tried this yet - I'll give it a try. Thanks very much!